# how to get the country of the user to use his language

Tags: ip-geolocation

i heard about many ways that depend of files like csv or database
but i think uploading an extra database on my site to do that is not good idea
i feel good about the external providers
is useing externial site that give your the country by the ip is good way
or its not good because the server will wait the response of the external provider and this will slow down the site?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz139.html

Comment: Not exactly, as you can see reading the csv file with binary search is very quick. Reading from websites is not good because they will ban you if you make too many connections.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not a great idea to base the language choice on the IP address anyway.  What if I'm an American browsing from Germany, and I don't speak German very well?  Your most standards-compliant way (I think) would be to parse the Accept-Language header of the web request, and use that to set a user's default, but *always* provide them a way to override the default and pick their language (which you'd then store in their session or user prefs)

Comment: i mean google method and i will make a chosing after that but i want the arabic for arabien and the en for others

Comment: Ok, you would still be best off using the accept-language header instead of the IP to sniff the language.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP variable **$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']** which, in my case, holds this value **sk,cs;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3**. 
That means, my browsers language is 'Slovak'.

I think, this option is better. Just imagine, that you are English, but you are on vacation somewhere.
You use your notebook over there... Your IP address would tell your server, that you are in Croatia and you'd like to get content in their language... But you browser still says you are english speaking person... There is the difference ;)

Comment: this mean site content depend on the broswer lang?

Comment: Exactly :) I thing, almost every user use web browser with his native language set as default. This is safe way to determine users language.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use GeoIP for this - there are too many scenarios when it fails or produces the wrong results.

As @Paul says the HTTP Accept-Language header specifies the user's language preferences as defined in the browser. You can view what your browser is set to by visiting [Browser Language Detection](http://aruljohn.com/lang.php).

For a real worked example see [Parse Accept-Language to detect a user's language](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header).

Also remember that crawlers don't use Accept-Language so it is important to ensure that you have a strategy for making this available (e.g URLs for each language content) and include in sitemap.

Also see [Apache Module mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) for content selection.